# Is READ_PHONE_STATE permission will be impacted by a change in the Google Play policy of SMS and CALL_LOG permissions groups?

Tags: android

**ERROR Alert** – this app will be impacted by a policy change
This app will be impacted by a change in the Google Play policy governing the use of **SMS and CALL_LOG** permissions. Apps that are not compliant may be removed from the Google Play on 9 Jan 2019.

I have removed the permission of SMS and CALL Permission group listed on Google policy link https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9047303 but not sure about `READ_PHONE_STATE.` Is this permission need to be removed? because its still showing that error alert.
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G87nL.png) is my manifest permission list.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you don't need to remove`READ_PHONE_STATE`, Google Play restricts only **SMS and Call logs** permission it's clearly mentioned in the [answer](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9047303)

If your app read Call Logs or SMS then you need to add the Call Log and SMS permission, else you need to remove it from your application **(Manifest.xml)**.

`READ_PHONE_STATE` only read IMEI Information, and dealing with the action when a call comes etc.  So you don't need to remove it from your app.

Comment: I have remove the SMS and Call logs permission but still showing that error alert

Comment: You need to remove it from Application too

Comment: what do you mean by Application too? Does it mean application tag in manifest

Comment: Read my answer, I mention Manifest File

Comment: already removed, In question I have shared my manifest permission list, sharing same image here https://i.stack.imgur.com/G87nL.png

Comment: Yes I See now You Updated it, just sit and relax, it takes time to process Google to check changes

Comment: Thanks Sniffer, Its takes time to get updated, the error is gone now